# Trying to store ssh command as variable - 'bad variable name'

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I'm writing a shell script in Jenkins.

I'm trying to store the output from this ssh command into a variable so I can perform some edits(grep) to the output.

```
export OUTPUT=$(ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${USER_AND_SERVER} "sudo hab svc status")
```

I keep getting a "bad variable name" error when I try to run this. I'm not sure if it's the fact I'm passing another variable in the ssh command 'USER_AND_SERVER'.

Comment: Maybe running the script with `set -x` will show the culprit...

Comment: Do you get the error from Jenkins, or from the shell ?

Comment: @dash-o the error was coming from the console output in jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below syntax. Assign the variable first without the export, and THEN do the export:

```
OUTPUT=$(ssh … )
export OUTPUT
```

Comment: @nullPointer this seems to have worked. removing the export seems to allow the command to run

Comment: @Sylvester apparently the shell you are running this with did not like the `export OUTPUT=…` syntax

Comment: @Sylvester  Which implied that this is unlikely to be bash. Consider re-tagging